# How do I get file ID from node?

Tags: 8, files

How can I get file ID like I got, for instance, file URI:

```
$getFile = $entity->get('field_file')->entity->getFileUri();
```

I need it to send an email (swiftmailer)

```
$file_one = file_load(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The file ID is the property `target_id` of the file field:

```
$fid = $entity->get('field_file')->target_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having $file object then you can get id from

```
$fid = $file->id();
```

and for loading purpose you can use the following

```
\Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
```