# How to get file fid value in paragraph and view templates

Tags: theming, paragraphs

Hi i am trying to access file `fid` value in paragraph twig template file but cant access it. Though I can print file uri but I need to access fid of the file

Here is my code in `paragraph.pdfdocument.html.twig` for printing file uri

```
{{ file_url(paragraph.field_brochure_file.entity.fileuri) }}
```

Same way I can print the file url in views template but not able to access `fid`  in `views-view-fields--my_view.html.twig` file

```
{{ fields.field_upload_pdf_file.content }}
```

Comment: You mean the ID of the entity you get `fileuri` from? Then replace `.entity.fileuri` with `.target_id`. Similar to this PHP question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246629/how-do-i-get-file-id-from-node

Comment: @4k4 it works for paragraph template. Thanks you very much. But I am still not able to figure out to print the fid of a file field in views-view-fields--my_view.html.twig file

Comment: The views field template is only a wrapper. Better rewrite the field results in UI, here you'll find tokens for the raw field properties like {{ field_example__target_id }}